# regex filter street number and zip from address

Tags: regex

I have some detail fields I need to filter out house number and zip but leave all other numbers in.

example 1:

```
Van: ION VORM.-VR.TIJD-SOC.TOER HOOGSTRAAT NR. 42 1000 BRUSSEL België IBAN: BE80877459990177 Mededeling: VK 60
```

example 2:

```
Van: SYND ABVV-REGIO ANTWERPEN OMMEGANCKSTRAAT 35 2018 ANTWERPEN België IBAN: BE15877800950130 Mededeling: VK38
```

in the first one I need to filter out `42` and `1000`, in the second `35` and `2018`

So basically I need a regex that will filter out the numbers from (any)straat(some chars that may include spaces)number(space)number

Thx

Comment: What regex tool/language are you using?

Comment: Is the first number always two digits and the next number always 4 digits? Then you can use this simple regex http://www.regexr.com/3b7oa

Comment: is the intervening text between `STRAAT` and the number either `" "` or `" NR. "`?

Answer (score 1):

This regex works for your two examples:

```
.+ ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+) .+
```

Live example: https://regex101.com/r/zA3fM9/1